# R: return value from first column in data frame based on closeness of inputted values to toher columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Teff logg M_div_H   U  B  V  R  I  J  H  K  L  Lprime  M
2000.0 4.0 -0.1 -13.443 -11.39 -7.895 -4.464 -1.831 1.666 3.511 2.701 4.345 4.765 5.68
2000.0 4.5 -0.1 -13.402 -11.416 -7.896 -4.454 -1.794 1.664 3.503 2.728 4.352 4.772 5.687
2000.0 5.0 -0.1 -13.358 -11.428 -7.888 -4.431 -1.738 1.664 3.488 2.753 4.361 4.779 5.685
2000.0 5.5 -0.1 -13.22 -11.079 -7.377 -4.136 -1.483 1.656 3.418 2.759 4.355 4.753 5.638
2200.0 3.5 -0.1 -11.866 -9.557 -6.378 -3.612 -1.185 1.892 3.294 2.608 3.929 4.289 4.842
2200.0 4.5 -0.1 -11.845 -9.643 -6.348 -3.589 -1.132 1.874 3.31 2.648 3.947 4.305 4.939
2200.0 5.5 -0.1 -11.655 -9.615 -6.279 -3.508 -0.997 1.886 3.279 2.709 3.964 4.314 4.928
2500.0 -1.02 -0.1 -7.41 -7.624 -6.204 -3.854 -1.533 1.884 3.32 2.873 3.598 3.964 5.579
2500.0 -0.7 -0.1 -7.008 -7.222 -5.818 -3.618 -1.338 1.905 3.266 2.868 3.502 3.877 5.417
...
```

Let's say I have two values:

```
input_Teff = 4.8529282904170595E+003
input_log_g = 1.9241934741026787E+000
```

I would like to find the row in the data frame that contains `Teff` and `logg` values closest to these input values, then ultimately get the `V` value (or for any other column) from that row. Is there a convenient way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question. You may need to define the closest here. Let's assume the smallest sum of two differences as the closest, then you could try something like this:

```
df$V[which.min(abs(df$Teff - input_Teff) + abs(df$logg - input_log_g))]
```

With `df` as your dataframe name.

Comment: Yes, by closest, I mean the smallest sum of two differences.